# I follow token fields for mongodb and i am stopped in saving tokens in my mongo collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, jquery-tokeninput

I have a author model

```
class Author
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name

end
```

In My article form i want to bring all authors

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author_tokens, "Authors" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :author_tokens, "data-pre"=> @article.authors.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
  </div>
```

It is working. all authors name are seen. now i want to submit all author name i click inside Authors. what should be my article model for this? I am confuse. Here when i publish

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"bE0PpLx+qBUJqIavfvpDOjzrhIHFku+IrgjnU0OLOC8=",
 "article"=>{"name"=>"ram",
 "published_on(1i)"=>"2012",
 "published_on(2i)"=>"8",
 "published_on(3i)"=>"20",
 "author_tokens"=>"",
 "content"=>"fdsfds"},
 "commit"=>"Create Article"}
```

author_tokens field is empty.
I have my article model

```
class Article

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  field :name
  field :content
  field :author_tokens
  field :token_inputs
 field :published_on, :type => Date 
 validates_presence_of :name,:content

has_many :authors
 attr_reader :author_tokens

 def author_tokens=(ids)
 self.author_ids =ids.split
 end

end
```

What should be my article model so that i can save all input author tokens name in my article collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Article model, try removing:

```
field :author_tokens
```

and adding:

```
attr_accessible :author_tokens
```

Also, not sure where the `token_inputs` field is getting used. Maybe unnecessary?

**EDIT:**

I overlooked this earlier, but you need `has_and_belongs_to_many` on both sides of the relation for this to even work the way you want, so:

```
Class Author
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
  ...
end
```

and:

```
Class Article
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
  # has_many :authors <- Remove this
  ...
end
```

To clarify my original explanation:

1) The setter method you wrote for `author_tokens` and the `attr_reader : author_tokens` are both fine, but if you're using mass assignment in the controller (likely), you need to make the `author_tokens` attribute mass assignable with `attr_accessible :author_tokens`. Mongoid might do this automatically if you haven't explicitly set anything else as `attr_accessible` yet, depending on what version you're using.

2) You shouldn't need the `field :author_tokens` line since it's a virtual attribute accessed via the setter you wrote, and the `attr_reader` call. You don't actually want to store the value the user passes into `author_tokens` in the DB, you want the setter to put those values into the `author_ids` field for you.

3) The `has_and_belongs_to_many :authors` call will have created the `author_ids` field in the document for you.

4) Assuming you're using the pattern shown [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields), the front-end implementation should be no different when using Mongoid instead of ActiveRecord.

Comment: I am using mongodb for database.

Comment: Mongoid supports `attr_accessible` just like AR. I can't see what's going on in your controller, but if using mass assignment, that's probably why your `author_tokens` field returns empty.

Comment: Do u have any idea of using jquery access token in mongodb in rails? I am able to pass id in author tokens n save in database but cant use edit .

Comment: You can't edit because your author ids from the tokenized input probably end up in the `author_tokens` field instead of the `author_ids` field, which is necessary for the relation to work. Also, you need to set this up as a has-and-belongs-to-many relation. See edited answer.

Comment: ya u are right . I am using jquery token input. since i am new in mongodb i get many errors. can u give me ur mail address so that i can forward my code to you?

Comment: Is there any idea not to select the name that is already choosen in token input? for example In first i select mango when i search for m. Next time again when i search for m Mango should not be displayed as mango is already choosen